# VBA Function for Inserting Columns in Two Locations, multiple times within worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, insert

I have a worksheet that contains various data, and two ranges of columns containing months X Y Z etc on same rows, one for cost spent and one for cost invoiced.

I have written code that duplicates another worksheet with the required format for entering the hard data. However I also need to input two additional columns to the rhs of the first month columns to allow for new months as required.

I started within this within the main code and works perfectly first time...

```
    Sheets("Cost").Range("K:K").EntireColumn.Insert
    Sheets("Cost").Range("O:O").EntireColumn.Insert
```

However the next time I generate a month obviously the ranges have changed and the vba places new columns in wrong place.

How can I dynamically update the range based for both locations?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably best to start at the end, i.e. the last column you have to insert.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by searching a value in row may be a fixed or by inputbox  or by selection by using this code that add column after the searched value
if you add a photo of a simple of your data could be easier to find better way

```
count = 0
Add = False
For Each cell In Sheets("Cost").Range("1:1")
   If Add Then
   cell.EntireColumn.Insert
   Add = False
   Count = Count + 1
   End If
    If cell.Value = "value to search" Then
        Add = True
        'MsgBox cell.Address
    End If
    
    If Count = 2 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

- The columns (from Col K to the right) will shift to right when you insert the first column. That is, `Columns("O")` is on Col P. Then the 2nd insertion are wrong.
- Insertion and deletion should be executed from the end to start.

```vb
    Sheets("Cost").Columns("O").Insert
    Sheets("Cost").Columns("K").Insert
```

- btw, `Columns("O")` is equivalent to `Range("K:K").EntireColumn`

[image]

> Question: However the next time I generate a month obviously the ranges have changed and the vba places new columns in wrong place.

- If you need to execute the code multiple times, you'd better to locate the column by the header. eg. assumes insert a column at Col J (cell J1 = "Col11")

```
Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range
    Const KEY = "Col11"
    Set c = Sheets("Cost").Rows(1).Find(KEY, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find " & KEY
    Else
        c.EntireColumn.Insert
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

an other idea its need three cells located in column before the first shift to store the name of columns and the number of shifting because it will effect the position of the second column thats by using 2 function asc() and chr() as follows

i used A1,A2,A3 you can use any other cells in any sheet

```
If Range("a1").Value = "" And Range("a2").Value = "" Then
    Sheets("Cost").Columns("O").Insert
    Sheets("Cost").Columns("K").Insert
    Range("a1").Value = "K"
    Range("a2").Value = "O"
    Range("a3").Value = 1
Else
Sheets("Cost").Columns(Chr(Asc(Range("a1").Value) + 1)).Insert
Range("a1").Value = Chr(Asc(Range("a1").Value) + 1)
Range("a3").Value = Range("a3").Value + 1
Sheets("Cost").Columns(Chr(Asc(Range("a2").Value) + 1 + Range("a3").Value)).Insert
Range("a2").Value = Chr(Asc(Range("a2").Value) + 1)
End If
End Sub
```